# google maps - Haversine formula with php not working

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation, haversine

My query for haversine formula is:

```
$query = "SELECT id, 
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM markers 
        HAVING distance < 25 
        ORDER BY distance 
        LIMIT 0 , 20;";
```

When use this formula, it returned an empty result set. No results found. Let me know the proper solution.

Also, use

```
select * FROM (
        SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( -33.898113 ) ) * cos( radians( 151.174469 ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( -33.898113 ) ) ) ) AS Distance FROM markers 
        ) as T 
    WHERE T.Distance < 25 
    ORDER BY T.Distance 
    LIMIT 0 , 20
```

this one, but return the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of `Stored Procedures` for finding nearest markers etc which seems to work well ~ I tried editing one for your purposes here - guessing that the two relevant columns are `lat` and `lng` - perhaps it will help

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spNearestMarkers`(
    IN `p_lat` DOUBLE,
    IN `p_lng` DOUBLE,
    IN `p_rad` INT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
proc:begin
    declare latitude double default 0;
    declare longitude double default 0;
    declare radius float default 0;
    declare earth_radius integer default 0;
    declare longitude_1 float;
    declare latitude_1 float;
    declare longitude_2 float;
    declare latitude_2 float;


    set @latitude=p_lat;
    set @longitude=p_lng;
    set @radius=p_rad;


    set @earth_radius=3956;
    set @longitude_1 = @longitude - @radius/abs( cos( radians(@latitude) ) * 69 );
    set @longitude_2 = @longitude + @radius/abs( cos( radians(@latitude) ) * 69 );
    set @latitude_1 = @latitude - (@radius/69);
    set @latitude_2 = @latitude + (@radius/69);



    select distinct
        *,
        round( @earth_radius * 2 * asin( sqrt( power( sin( ( @latitude - m.`lat` ) * pi()/180 / 2 ), 2 ) + cos( @latitude * pi()/180 ) * cos( m.`lat` * pi()/180) *power( sin( ( @longitude - m.`lng`) * pi()/180 / 2 ), 2) ) ) , 2 ) as 'distance'
    from `markers` m
    where
        ( m.`lat` between @latitude_1 and @latitude_2 ) 
            and 
        ( m.`lng` between @longitude_1 and @longitude_2 )

    group by m.`name`
    having `distance` <= @radius
    order by `distance`;

    set @latitude=null;
    set @longitude=null;
    set @radius=null;
    set @longitude_1 = null;
    set @longitude_2 = null;
    set @latitude1 = null;
    set @latitude2 = null;

end
```

To call the procedure in php

```
$lat=-33.74788;
$lng=151.23526;
$radius=10;

$sql="call `spNearestMarkers`('$lat','$lng','$radius');`";
```

Or, to call the procedure in mysql ( gui )

```
set @_lat=-33.74788;
set @_lng=151.23526;
set @_radius=10;

call `spNearestMarkers`(@_lat,@_lng,@_radius);
```

The above returns:

```
"id","name","address","lat","lng","distance",
"1","Heir Apparel","Crowea Pl, Frenchs Forest NSW 2086","-33.737885","151.235260","0.69",
"4","The Legacy","Charlotte Ln, Chatswood NSW 2067","-33.796669","151.183609","4.49",
"6","Trish & Tash","Lincoln St, Lane Cove West NSW 2066","-33.812222","151.143707","6.88",
"10","Moda Couture","Northcote Rd, Glebe NSW 2037","-33.873882","151.177460","9.31",
```

Assuming your database has columns `latitude` and `longitude` and you are trying to invoke the sql query from PHP then

```
/* the lat/lng of the location you are trying to find places nearby */
$lat=56.25;
$lng=-2.65;

$sql="SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0,20;";
```

Comment: I'm using the WordPress post meta table, where I store lat, long as a meta_key. Can you please suggest me how can I fetch the data using this query.

Comment: Your original sql query suggests the clumns are called `lat` and `lng` rather than `lat` and `long`. I know nothing of Wordpress ut that should not matter - presumably you can create a stored procedure on your database? If so, try creating one as above and running that ( edit column names if they are incorrect )

Comment: My question is that why not working this query and why it's returned an empty result set?

Comment: You have a vastly different formula ~ where did it come from?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator

Comment: The formula - you are using that EXACTLY as from Google? Does your database have lat/lng near to those in the formula??? You have to put your own values into that formula

Comment: Yes, I put down my own value. Also, I created same table data from google

Comment: OK - I just did the same: created their table, added their data and ran their query... zilch, nothing, nada, nothing!!! ~ if you set the distance to 25000 though it does sort of work

Comment: Yes, this code is not working properly. I want to the list all places within 25 km using lat lng.

Need to know how can I overcome this problem. Can you suggest me any solution